# How to implement REST API Request URL/Headers/Body into https or code

Tags: json, api, rest

I am working with Sabre's API (https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs).  The documentation could leave a lot to be desired, especially for a noob.  Sabre is giving me the following details to call a response that shows rental car availability.  However I have no clue - do I take this data and load a HTTPS/URL?  Do I write this into python code and execute it?  Please help!

Request URI

```
https://api.test.sabre.com/v2.4.0/shop/cars
```

Request Headers

```
Authorization: Bearer T1RLAQI5V/zSp6o3WmZG10MSbQkPEkUShBCE+Bj0dkKsBv3/Rpv3u5ckAACgYUiSgZpk607+Y43m/veg1TSblwgOZPOpduj+Fa27070vBZfaWKmXT5od66o3K1C/N6Hu9KKniZC2fuplXuMkATtUEprzy8eud+Mz9e/0WVcqeQrnu3Z9Y/79WNDW3JGyxk8Gb05h5rdjavFPBHJaJE/ROPqw7fIsGZyj56EVEyP4BmcsWj3BSJkBEjBnon82Re5IPH94ntmX/HpiI/7V+g**
```

X-Originating-Ip: 98.116.41.181
Content-Type: application/json

Request Body

```
{

"OTA_VehAvailRateRQ": {

  "VehAvailRQCore": {

    "QueryType": "Shop",

    "VehRentalCore": {

      "PickUpDateTime": "04-08T09:00",

      "ReturnDateTime": "04-09T11:00",

      "PickUpLocation": {

        "LocationCode": "DFW"

      }

    }

  }

}

}
```

Comment: It seems they expect you to send a Json content-type as the request. This means that you'll send an HTTP POST request with Json data in the body. If they request some specific headers you must add them in the request.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example of how you would call something?  Thanks

Comment: What specific language are you using?

Comment: Python, but I'd like to also call this in https

Comment: Ok, I'm not into Python too much, so I can't tell you know how it is. You have to look for "performing http" requests in python. There is a know library called `curl` that you use to make HTTP(S) requests from command line, and major languages also have libraries that wrap the cURL behaviour. Look for `curl applied to python` and you'll be in the good track.